# Aggregating multiple mysql tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have 3 MySQL tables that are below (I used excel to show example of my tables)

[image]

[image]

[image]

My intended result table is below
[image]

I have tried sql below but i am not getting desired above result

```
select count(TableA.code),sum(TableB.Mass),count(TableC.Code) from 
TableB left join TableA on TableA.Code = TableB.Code left join TableC on 
TableA.Code = TableC.Code
group  by TableB.Grade

enter code here
```

Comment: İ think there is an error in logic. what is Price stands for ?  there is only Mass on desired output

Comment: I think for AB table C count and mass will be 0. Please check and confirm.

Comment: @AliFidanli ,I am not interested in price in the final table ,so we can leave price.When i am saying Table A(Code count) ,im saying in (Table A how many codes have grade AA ,and how many have grade AB in TableB).I hope i made it more clear

Comment: @RahulBiswas,you are correct ,let me correct that one

Comment: @Herbert please check my answer below and let me know if it's helped.

Answer (score 1):

As per your given sample and desired result table C count and mass will be retrieved based on active status. That's why conditional CASE statement is used for table C value calculation.

```
 -- MySQL
SELECT b.grade
     , COUNT(a.code) "Table A (Code Count)"
     , SUM(b.Mass) "Table A (Total Mass)"
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN c.status = 'Active' THEN c.Code END) "Table C (Code Count)"
     , COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN c.status = 'Active' THEN b.Mass END), 0) "Table C (Total Mass)"
FROM TableB b 
LEFT JOIN TableA a
       ON a.code = b.code 
LEFT JOIN TableC c
       ON c.code = b.code
GROUP BY b.grade
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43a9548e7bbdf049928982580e1a2cdd

Comment: @Herbert if my answer helps you then please mark it as accepted (Green tick) along with upvote so that any one can pick this answer when they search related things.